# Called start() method twice on same thread in java, sometimes it executes run() method twice; What exactly happens internally?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my piece of code ran on java version "1.8.0_121"

```
class ThreadTest extends Thread
{
   ThreadTest()
   {
     run();
   }    

   public void run()
   {
     System.out.println("In run");
   }
}

class ThreadDemo
{
   public static void main(String a[])
   {
      ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
      t.start();
      System.out.println("Main after start 1 ");    
      t.start();    
      System.out.println("Main after start 2 ");    
   }
}
```

Please see the output of above code

```
In run
Main after start 1
In run
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at InheritanceChild.main(InheritanceChild.java:44)
C:\Java>
```

I searched on various post but they only tell that java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException occurs when you try to call start method twice on same thread in java.
   But in my case it is executing run() method twice before throwing java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException.
   Can anyone please advice me over, what exactly happening internally; I mean flow of code execution. (how it is making second run() call at the first place? and at which moment throws an exception ?)

Comment: You are calling `run` in your constructor as well. You cannot "restart" a thead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling run() method from Constructor, that's first execution when you create object. Second one is when you actually start a thread execution and exception is for second start call.

Thread start document clearly says "It is never legal to start a thread more than once".

> public void start()
>           Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>           The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and
>   the other thread (which executes its run method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.
>
> Throws:
>           IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

Answer (score 2):

It's not `start()` that's calling `run()` twice. Your constructor also calls `run()`. Remove the second `start()` and you'll still see it called twice.